# How do I set date format to `YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS` in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, postgresql-9.1

I can use the `to_char` function to convert it to `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` and it comes out correctly but I want the space between the `DD` and `HH to be replaced by the letter 'T'.

If I use `YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS` then I get, for example, `2014-06-09THH24:58:30`.

How can I get the format I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way:

```
SELECT to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS ')
```

You can throw in anything between *double quotes* to output literally.